# c++ seg fault on std::string destructor, only when variable is passed

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, destructor, stdstring

This problem is occurring in the middle of a lot of busy functions, so I'm going to try to explain the problem with pseudo-code in the hopes that it is sufficient.  I'm equally interested in understanding the underlying problem as with solving it, so I'd appreciate explanations in addition to fixes.  Thanks!

'methodOne' retrieves std::string xx from another function, and sends it, along with strings x1, x2 and x3 (all from a new object) to 'methodTwo'.

```
bool methodOne(...) {
    Object1 obj = Object1(...);
    string xx = obj.someFunction(...);
    methodTwo(xx, obj.getX1(), obj.getX2(), obj.getX3() );
    ...
    return true;
}
```

'methodTwo' (in Object2) then combines these strings into a vector, and passes them to 'methodThree'.

```
bool Object2::methodTwo(const string xx, const string x1, const string x2, const string x3) {
   vector<string> holder;      // alternate - comment out this line
   holder.push_back(xx);       //             and this line,
   // vector<string> holder(1, "test");    // alternate - uncomment this line
   holder.push_back(x1);
   holder.push_back(x2);
   holder.push_back(x3);
   ...
   obj3.methodThree( holder );
   ...
   return true;
}          // line 443 - where error is backtraced to
```

Finally, 'methodThree' ends-up creating a few files, all four strings are printed to one of them.

Running the program, i get a segmentation fault, from gdb :

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory. Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000 0x00007fff8f1e3aa2 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
>::~basic_string () (gdb) where
#0  0x00007fff8f1e3aa2 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string ()
#1  0x0000000100009f18 in std::_Destroy<std::string> ()
#2  0x0000000100009f3e in std::__destroy_aux<std::string*> ()
#3  0x0000000100009f9f in std::_Destroy<std::string*> ()
#4  0x0000000100009fd7 in std::_Destroy<std::string*, std::string> ()
#5  0x0000000100060115 in std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::~vector (this=0x7fff5fbfd488) at stl_vector.h:271
#6  0x0000000100013b9f in Station::methodTwo (this=0x7fff5fbff110, foreFN=@0x7fff5fbfdf08, startDT=@0x7fff5fbfded8, stopDT=@0x7fff5fbfdea8, numElems=169, tCase=0x7fff5fbfe7c8) at Station.cpp:443
#7  0x0000000100002b45 in methodOne ()
#8  0x000000010000707a in main ()
```

In 'methodTwo', if I replace string 'xx' with some random test string, the error goes away.  So the problem has to be with 'xx' --- which is also the only string in 'methodOne' which is not coming from Object1 obj.

I was thinking that some constructor wasn't actually duplicating the string (is shallow copying the term?) so I tried doing things like calling methodTwo as

```
methodTwo( string(xx), obj.getX1() ...)
```

or when constructing the vector, using something like

```
holder.push_back( string(xx) );
```

but neither of those things worked.

I'm at a complete loss, I'd appreciate any help / tips anyone has.  I know its annoying since I haven't given a coherent code that can reproduce the problem, or even the actual code --- but hopefully this is enough for someone wiser than myself to see something.

thanks

---

New weirdness:

from the comments below, it sounds like its very possible the actual error is somewhere else, infecting the heap.  But, because `xx` is only distinguished by *not* being retrieved from `obj`, I tried adding `xx` to the object --- i.e. in another method called earlier, the variable `xx` is set to the same thing resulting value as it should have been before...

```
string Object1::someFunction(...) {
    ...
    string val = ...;
    setXX(val);
    cout << getXX() << endl;         // this *correctly* prints the value of xx
    ...
    return val;
}
void Object1::setXX(string temp) { xx = string(temp); }
string Object1::getXX() { return xx; }
```

and then I retrieve xx in the `methodTwo` call:

```
methodTwo(obj.getXX(), obj.getX1() ... );
```

and that has **stopped the error, but** `xx` **wont store the string!!!**  I.e.

```
obj.someFunction(...);          // this is able to set and retrieve xx
cout << obj.getXX() << endl;    //  prints **blank line!!**
methodTwo(obj.getXX(), obj.getX1() ...);   // no more error, x1 x2 x3 are fine, xx is empty!
```

Now I feel like I'm going crazy....

Comment: You'll need to create something demonstrating the problem. With the given information you probably left out some crucial detail: Based on what you said, it looks as if it should work. Most like you corrupted the heap somewhere and your are observing a problem at a location where things are already broken.

Comment: Are you using a GCC from MacPorts, or some other GCC that didn't come with XCode?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm pretty sure I'm using the XCode version.  `g++ --version` yields: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Please provide a small, contained, code sample that reproduces the issue you face.

Comment: `string xx = someFunction(...);` does not match with `void Object1::someFunction(...)`...

Comment: @PiotrNycz, its pseudo-code... but I fixed that.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi, as It would be quite difficult to do that -- I thought I'd try this first.  If it doesn't help, I will procede to explore making a small, reproducible version.  It seemed like the logical way to procede.

Comment: Double check that you always returns std::string from your someFunction(). Give us the real code of this function - I guess problem could be there. Pseudo-code is not enough for problems like yours... Try to make the smallest possible example which produces wrong behavior, then it will be obvious what is wrong - if not present it here on SO...

Comment: The problem with pseudo-code in this case is that your problem is almost certainly something you don't understand.  So when you abstract away the code, you don't include the part that is causing the problem.  Which is why you need a complete, compiling example of the problem occurring.  This is also good practice for yourself, because breaking a problem down into a simple case where it occurs without the mess is how you solve these problems when you run into them without having to ask for help.

Answer (score 3):

When you crash inside a memory allocator it is rare that you can trace the problem to the exact memory being freed (or allocated) at the instant of the crash.  The allocator will have sanity checks that will usually catch attempts to free invalid pointers (pointers that aren't pointing to the beginning of some allocation, pointers outside the bounds of the heap, duplicate frees, etc).  The most common cause of crashes in the memory allocator is heap corruption.  Often freed chunks are chained to other free chunks using a small structure at the front of the chunk.  Writing on freed memory or writing beyond an allocated block will corrupt these pointers and cause crashes in the allocator.

I would expect that if your *alternate* program ran long enough after avoiding the initial crash there would eventually be another crash anyway.  The pattern you've observed with `xx` might be as simple as the length of `xx` being much different than `x1`..`x3` and thus being allocated from a different memory pool.

Here's a test to try:  Does the program still crash if you just put `return` at the top of `methodThree`?

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that was already insightful.  It **is** the case that `xx` is a good deal larger than `x1`...`x3`.  But, calling `return` at the beginning of `methodThree` does *not* help, the error still occurs at the same place.  I've added another weird thing to the initial problem statement above... maybe that will help :/